# Prove that with $x,y,z>0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Let $x,y,z>0$
Prove that:
$$
\left ( \dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{2}{y+z}+\dfrac{3}{x+y+z} \right )^2+\left ( \dfrac{1}{y}+\dfrac{2}{x+z}+\dfrac{3}{x+y+z} \right )^2+\left ( \dfrac{1}{z}+\dfrac{2}{y+x}+\dfrac{3}{x+y+z} \right )^2-\dfrac{81}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\geq 0$$

Answer (score 4):

[Cauchy Schwarz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) & [Nesbitt's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesbitt%27s_inequality):

$$\begin{aligned}\Bigg[x^2+y^2+z^2\Bigg]\Bigg[\sum_{x,y,z}\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2}{y+z}+\frac{3}{x+y+z}\right)^2\Bigg]&\geq  \Bigg[\sum_{x,y,z}\left( 1+\frac{2x}{y+z}+\frac{3x}{x+y+z}\right)\Bigg]^2\\&=\Bigg[6+\sum_{x,y,z}\frac{2x}{y+z}\Bigg]^2\\&\geq 9^2\end{aligned}$$